# Splitting email id and taking 10 ids each time by condition

Tags: c#, .net

I have email id with semicolon separated. I have to split it and take each 10 ids send email.
For example if I have 44 email ids in the list then I have to trigger it in 5 times, 4 time I will send 10 and last time will send 4.

```
string[] torecipients = to.Split(';');
string receivers = string.Empty;

for (int i = 0; i <= torecipients.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (torecipients[i] != ";")
    {
        receivers = receivers + ";" + torecipients[i];                               


    }                       
}
```

I tried `torecipients.take(10).Tolist()` After that I got stuck.

Comment: use combination of skip and take . check my posted answer..

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ArraySegment<T>` to take batches of your split list of recipients.

```
    var batchSize = 10;
    string[] torecipients = to.Split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < torecipients.Length; i+= batchSize)
    {
        int count = (i + batchSize < torecipients.Length)
            ? batchSize
            : torecipients.Length - i;

        var receivers = new ArraySegment<string>(torecipients, i, count);
        // Send email to each batch
    }
```

Comment: It's a nice solution; however `new ArraySegment<string>()` will throw an exception in the last iteration if there are not `batchSize` items left.

Answer (score 1):

Use skip and take combination like as below:

```
        string[] torecipients = to.Split(new char[] { ';' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string receivers = string.Empty;

        int n = (torecipients.Length / 10) + 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            receivers = string.Join(";",torecipients.Skip(10*i).Take(10));

             // Mail sending code here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage Regex:

```
IEnumerable<string> groups = Regex.Matches(to, @"(.+?(;|$)){1,10}").Select(m => m.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to find a simple solution close to your code.
This should do it for you:

```
    string[] torecipients = to.Split(';');
    string receivers = string.Empty;
    int  l=0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= torecipients.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (torecipients[i] != ";")
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(receivers)){
                receivers = torecipients[i];    
                l++;
            }else if(l==10)
            {
                //Send emails to receivers
                receivers = string.Empty;
                l=0;
            }else
            {
                receivers = receivers + ";" + torecipients[i];
                l++;
            }       
    }                       
}
```

Basically added an int to check how many emails you already have on receivers and check if it is empty or full

Comment: hi Lourenco, welcome to SO. your suggestion is riddled with problems, you may to make another pass. a couple of fairly obvious ones for example: `if(receivers == "")` *should* be `if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(receivers))`. `else if(l==10)` should be handled using the `%` modulus operator. IMHO, when there are so many nested elements, the code tends to be fragile and hard to follow/reason/extend.

Comment: Hi Shai, thanks for the corrections. If I may ask, what are the advantages of those 2 corrections? I kinda understand the first one, but not the second one, why should the `else if (l==10)` be handled using the % modulus operator?

Comment: I agree with you in that they are *functionally* the same. However, your solution requires both an added variable (not that big a deal, I agree) and *4 additional lines of code* to manage the state of `l` sprinkled throughout your method. Modulus would require nothing additional, be cleaner because there is no state management and, this one is more important than many realize, when I see a modulus condition I inherently *know* what is happening in that piece of code.  That's not the case when using `l`.